# Ubuntu 20.04 freezes for no apparent reason, media continues to play, mouse moves but click doesn't work

Tags: 20.04, freeze

tired of running out of resources, two months ago I moved Ubuntu (new install) 20.04 to a HP ZBook 15 G6, Intel Quad-core CPU, with 48GB RAM, thinking it will never run out of RAM or CPU usage.

But already twice, the system seems to freeze for no apparent reason, the media (my Udemy course) continue to play. The mouse moves, but not reacting to clicking. Even my Virtualbox lab processes seem to be running, except I can't access them.

I have to press the power button to do a cold start. Below is the output from `lspci`. Does any of them raise an alarm?

@heynnema

ls -al /var/crash

```
total 8
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 Mar  3 10:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root     4096 Feb  3 21:40 ..
```

free -h

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           46Gi       4.4Gi        39Gi       518Mi       2.6Gi        41Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi
```

sudo lshw -C memory

```
  *-firmware                
       description: BIOS
       vendor: HP
       physical id: 0
       version: R92 Ver. 01.07.01
       date: 10/19/2020
       size: 64KiB
       capacity: 32MiB
       capabilities: pci pcmcia upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int5printscreen int9keyboard int14serial int17printer acpi usb smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
  *-memory
       description: System Memory
       physical id: 6
       slot: System board or motherboard
       size: 48GiB
     *-bank:0
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2667 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: M471A2K43CB1-CTD
          vendor: Samsung
          physical id: 0
          serial: 13F78110
          slot: Top-Slot 1(left)
          size: 16GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2667MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:1
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 1
          slot: Top-Slot 2(right)
     *-bank:2
          description: SODIMM DDR4 Synchronous 2667 MHz (0.4 ns)
          product: 16ATF4G64HZ-2G6B2
          vendor: Micron
          physical id: 2
          serial: 2612692F
          slot: Bottom-Slot 1(left)
          size: 32GiB
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 2667MHz (0.4ns)
     *-bank:3
          description: [empty]
          physical id: 3
          slot: Bottom-Slot 2(right)
  *-cache:0
       description: L1 cache
       physical id: 11
       slot: L1 Cache
       size: 384KiB
       capacity: 384KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=1
  *-cache:1
       description: L2 cache
       physical id: 12
       slot: L2 Cache
       size: 1536KiB
       capacity: 1536KiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=2
  *-cache:2
       description: L3 cache
       physical id: 13
       slot: L3 Cache
       size: 12MiB
       capacity: 12MiB
       capabilities: synchronous internal write-back unified
       configuration: level=3
  *-memory UNCLAIMED
       description: RAM memory
       product: Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
       version: 10
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz (30.3ns)
       capabilities: pm cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:400-3ff memory:ed332000-ed333fff memory:404a112000-404a112fff
```

sysctl vm.swappiness

```
vm.swappiness = 60
```

grep -i swap /etc/fstab

```
/swapfile                                 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

sudo swapon -s

```
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/swapfile                               file        2097148 0   -2
```

Comment: Have you installed the proprietary drivers for the "Nvidia Quadro T1000 Mobile"? If so, which version?

Comment: Can you get to a console? <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> (or possibly <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> ).

Comment: Edit your question and show me `ls -al /var/crash` and `free -h` and `sudo lshw -C memory` and `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `grep -i swap /etc/fstab` and `sudo swapon -s`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema  
ls -al /var/crash
total 8
drwxrwsrwt  2 root whoopsie 4096 Mar  3 10:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 14 root root     4096 Feb  3 21:40 ..

free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           46Gi       4.4Gi        39Gi       518Mi       2.6Gi        41Gi
Swap:         2.0Gi          0B       2.0Gi

More see edited question. thanks a lot.

Comment: @ChanganAuto. No I didn't install any proprietary driver. Just the one installed at Ubuntu installation. How to find out which driver I'm using?

Comment: I'm not sure if I tried, but next time, I'll make sure to try Ctrl + Alt + T.

Comment: Please see my answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

**BIOS**

You have BIOS R92 Ver. 01.07.01 dated 10/19/2020. There' a newer BIOS available, version 01.08.02 Rev.A, dated Jan 29, 2021, and can be downloaded [here](https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/hp-zbook-15-g6-mobile-workstation/22892887).

**Note**: Confirm that I have the correct web page for your model #.

**Note**: Have good backups before updating the BIOS.

**vm.swappiness**

With 48G RAM, we can tweak vm.swappiness to reduce swapping. Edit /etc/sysctl.conf and add `vm.swappiness=10`, then do `sudo sysctl -p` or `reboot`.

**memory**

With 48G RAM, you have an odd size amount of RAM, and because you have dis-similar SODIMMs, you don't get the speed advantage of memory interleaving. Assuming that you only have two SODIMM slots, recommend replacing one/both current SODIMMs with similar size/spec SODIMMs... ie: two 16G, or two 32G (check the maximum memory capacity specs for your model #).

**swap**

After setting vm.swappiness, we really shouldn't see too much swap activity, however 2G /swapfile is really too small. We'll change it to 4G...

**Note**: Incorrect use of the `rm` and `dd` commands can cause data loss. Suggest copy/paste.

In the `terminal`...

```
sudo swapoff -a           # turn off swap
sudo rm -i /swapfile      # remove old /swapfile

sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=4096

sudo chmod 600 /swapfile  # set proper file protections
sudo mkswap /swapfile     # init /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile     # turn on swap
free -h                   # confirm 48G RAM and 4G swap
```

Edit /etc/fstab, using `sudo -H gedit /etc/fstab` or `sudo pico /etc/fstab`.

Confirm this /swapfile line in /etc/fstab... and confirm no other “swap” lines... use SPACES in this line... confirm NO TABS...

```
/swapfile  none  swap  sw  0  0
```

---

```
reboot                    # reboot and verify operation
```